# How to send text SMS message into specific app in android with out making your app default message app?

Tags: android, smsmanager, android-sms

I have searched the internet and stackoverflow and there are many similar question but non of them help me to solve my problem. I have an android application that sends and accept text message(not for messaging purpose). I have used the following code to send the sms text message.

```
void sendSMS(Context context, final String smsTo,final String message) {
      mContext=context;
       String SMS_SENT = "SMS SENT";

       PendingIntent sentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0);
       String SMS_DELIVERED = "SMS DELIVERED";
       PendingIntent deliveredPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0);
       //for sms SENT
       mContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               switch (getResultCode()) {
                   case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                       Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       break;
                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                       Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure cause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       sendMessage.sendHTTP(mContext,smsTo, message);
                       break;
                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                       Toast.makeText(context, "Service is currently unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       sendMessage.sendHTTP(mContext,smsTo, message);
                       break;
                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                       Toast.makeText(context, "No pdu provided", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       sendMessage.sendHTTP(mContext,smsTo, message);
                       break;
                   case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                       Toast.makeText(context, "Radio was explicitly turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       sendMessage.sendHTTP(mContext,smsTo, message);
                       break;
               }
           }
       }, new IntentFilter(SMS_SENT));
//for sms Receive
        mContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }

            }
        },new IntentFilter(SMS_DELIVERED));

       SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();



       smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsTo, null, message, sentPendingIntent, deliveredPendingIntent);
   }
```

And i have also a receiver

```
 public class SMSReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        mContext=context;
        SmsMessage[] smsMessage=null;
        String stringMessage=null;
        if(bundle!=null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"message recieved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Object[] pdus= (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
            smsMessage=new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            // For every SMS message received
            for (int i=0; i < smsMessage.length; i++) {
                smsMessage[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                stringMessage=smsMessage[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress()+" "+ smsMessage[i].getMessageBody();
            }
            if(stringMessage!=null) {
                //accept the message do something.
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And i have also registered the broadcast receiver in AndroidManifest.xml file as follow

```
<receiver
            android:name=".SMSReceive"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECIEVED"></action>
             </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The text message is successfully sent and delivered to phone but the default message app is receiving the text message my app is not receiving the text message.

Comment: Did you add Run time Permission

Comment: Add Runtime Permissions and Watch Carefully whether the Toast is Shown.

Comment: are you talking about a Runtime Perimission for android Marshmallow and above? if so i have a run time permission for Marshmallow and above.

Comment: Yup. Do you added Run Time Permissions

Comment: yes i have added.

Answer (score 1):

```
android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECIEVED
```

Change that to:

```
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
```

or, copy and paste the value from [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION).

Comment: Thanks, How to make my app only receive the text message?

Comment: @Yirga: On Android 4.4-7.1, that is not possible, at least for regular text messages. On Android 8.0+, depending on what you are doing, you may be able to take advantage of [SMS tokens](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#createAppSpecificSmsToken(android.app.PendingIntent)).

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need the permission for reading receiving sms in `AndroidManifest`  :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

and also runtime permission for READ_SMS
then as for your broadcast receiver :

```
 <receiver android:name=".network.SmsBroadcastReceiver">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data
                android:port="1396"
                android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

as you can see in the `intent-filter` with `DATA_SMS_RECEIVED` you can also add port number if you want that only your app be able to view the message and not any other app and also it wont go into default messaging apps inbox.
but i am not sure of the part whether you can send Data_sms with android and also add port number to it cause as for my experience this is done by my Server and not an android app.
so if you couldn't send over specific port you can remove :

```
<data
  android:port="1396"
  android:scheme="sms" />
```

it should also work.

hope this helps

Comment: I will try your answer but if i add port number when registering receiver. how can i send the port number with the message in             SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsTo, null, message, sentPendingIntent, deliveredPendingIntent);

Comment: @Yirga You would use the [`sendDataMessage()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendDataMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20short,%20byte[],%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) instead.